# pythonw.exe stopped working, can't run IDLE or any .py files

Tags: python, crash, installation

This issue doesn't pertain to any code exactly.  I think my installation (python 3.3.5) became corrupted somehow.  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling, as well as repairing, but nothing has worked.  It's been a while since I last ran any python code or did anything involving python, really, so I can't say I accidentally messed up my own install.  The only thing I can think of which might be an issue is installation and updates of Blender to 2.7.

Comment: I think you should post this issue to [superuser](http://superuser.com) instead of here. I'm sure they would be more helpful

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if this was even the right place, since it doesn't deal with code at all.

Comment: You're welcome. Just cut this one and paste it there :)

Comment: @alKid Firstly, questions relating to software development tools (including IDEs) are on-topic on SO as per your help docs. Secondly, please don't encourage cross-posting - migration exists for a reason (however, in this case, the question should not be migrated except maybe if the OP requests it - since it's acceptable on SO anyway).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out uninstalling Blender, uninstalling Python, reinstalling Python and then reinstalling Blender(optional) did the trick.  Blender 2.70 has some Python 3.4 libraries bundled with it on installation, but I'm guessing for some reason, having an older version of Python already installed caused conflicts/dependency issues/wh.  I'd love to know the details on why, but for now I'm just glad I can run python scripts again.